# routes in angular and nodejs deployed app not working

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I have deloyed a nodejs and angular app on heroku but after deployed routes are not working.
here is my webiste - https://murti123.herokuapp.com
with routes - [enter link description here](https://murti123.herokuapp.com/contacts)

but with routes it gives a `can't get /` errror.
i don't know how to resolve it

[Here is My project Structure`enter code here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghiW7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `resolve` your path to the frontend application

so assume that in `/public` folder you have the dist files from the builded frontend application

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

and here you resolve that index.html for any route

```js
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  //path is required at the top of the file ofcourse
  //const path = require("path"); 
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
});
```

Comment: If this answers your question you can mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: is this path is any dependency?

Comment: 'is this path is any dependency?' -- it is built-in module provided with Node.js